# What are "Hollywood Twin" beds?

Tags: hotels, sleeping

The rather swanky Andaz Singapore advertises that some of its rooms, like [this one](https://www.hyatt.com/en-US/hotel/singapore/andaz-singapore/sinaz/rooms/suites/AZXT), have "Hollywood Twin beds".  No further detail is provided, although from the picture the beds look a little larger than usual:

[image]
(courtesy Andaz, not freely licensed but I'm sure they won't mind the free advertising)

**What exactly are Hollywood Twin beds?**

Comment: That photo looks horizontally stretched out, so the beds may not actually be larger than usual.

Comment: @shoover That's probably correct; it is shot wide angle to make the room look bigger. The pillows on the foreground bed, probably both beds, also have been pushed to right of center to make the beds look larger, as well.

Comment: @shoover / travelgasm I'm fairly sure this image is a render. This is common with newish hotels, as they'll produce PR images before the hotel has been finished.

Comment: @StrangerToKindness I don't think so, I've stayed here and the hotel rooms really do look like that.  Of course there's professional lighting and wide angle lenses in use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, "Hollywood Twin" can be used to refer to a hotel room set up with two "single" beds intended for one person each — sometimes called "twin" beds — and that usually share a headboard.

The idea is that the two beds can be easily configured separately or pushed together and sometimes "zipped" together to form a single larger bed, as well. Here is at least [one credible source](https://www.hotel-east21.co.jp/en/stay/rooms/hollywoodtwin.php) — a hotel in Tokyo — that defines the term as just two beds "arranged side by side" in a close configuration. Another hotel in Okinawa [mentions](https://www.mercureokinawanaha.jp/en/rooms-suites/standard-twin-room/) the "zip" beds option. A "California King" refers to a specific — and [gigantic](https://www.serta.com/comfort-101/mattress-guide/king-size-mattress-dimensions) — US mattress size, but Hollywood Twin does not.

My understanding always has been that the "Hollywood" in this naming convention is a nod to classic 1950s Hollywood sitcom [*I Love Lucy*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043208/) and similar programs. Throughout its run, I Love Lucy had [various studio-imposed/self-censorship requirements](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SleepingSingle) — sometimes referred to as the Hays code in legal circles — for the characters' bedding options.

In *I Love Lucy*, the beds sometimes were [configured separately](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SleepingSingle) with one character expected to keep a foot on the floor. Other times, the beds were allowed to be pushed together, but they had to be [visibly separate with separate blankets](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/lucille-ball-and-desi-arnaz-portray-lucy-ricardo-and-ricky-news-photo/631977676) (as demonstrated by iconic Getty Images photos from the show). This *configurability* of the twin beds in Hollywood of this era likely is what lends Hollywood Twin its name in a hotel context, as well.

Comment: It wasn't just I love Lucy. Hollywood itself had a lot of restrictions imposed on them via the [Hays code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hays_Code) during that era.

Comment: Oops .. didn't see that one of your links was to the Hays code via the tropes

Comment: @PeterM Indeed. I can elaborate if you think it is worthwhile; was just trying to keep the answer fairly succinct. Believe that I Love Lucy generally is considered the most notable example of the *configurability* of the twin beds, but there no doubt are others, etc.

Comment: My confusion was because you hid the Hays code under text that said "self imposed".    While the Hays code may have been self imposed by the studios, stepping out of line did result in movies being kept out of theaters. I also have a vague memory that the Hays code wasn't directly applicable to TV and that there was another self-censorship system in place..

Comment: @PeterM It's been updated with a bit more detail; I'm happy to change anything you think is incorrect or should be clarified further. It has been a while since film school as well, but Desilu had a lot of official control over the product. Believe that the unofficial control commonly was more related to advertiser expectations than formal/legal censorship, etc.

Comment: This is quite a tangent, but it actually [isn't a complete fabrication for television](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2019/aug/16/rolled-over-why-did-married-couples-stop-sleeping-in-twin-beds): *"By the 1920s, twin beds were seen as a fashionable, modern choice. “Separate beds for every sleeper are as necessary as are separate dishes for every eater,” wrote Dr Edwin Bowers in his 1919 volume, Sleeping for Health. “They promote comfort, cleanliness, and the natural delicacy that exists among human beings.”"*. For the time period described, this would be comfortably within living memory.

Comment: to extend the tangent with an anecdote: my grandparents and that grandmother's parents also had separate single beds, so it is absolutely not a TV invention.

Comment: @Yorik The answer doesn't state that two single beds are a TV invention. The *configurability* of the twin beds is the reason for the Hollywood Twin term for a hotel room. The two beds can be configured either apart (sometimes barely) or together (sometimes even zipped together) and generally share a headboard so that it works regardless of the arrangement. In shows of this era, and *I Love Lucy*, specifically, the arrangement of twin beds changed frequently and there commonly were two twin beds with a shared headboard.

Comment: @travelgasm read the prior comment to mine "...isn't a complete fabrication..." I think I was clear that I was referring to this tangential comment

Comment: @PeterM+ yes, Hays was only movies. TV (and radio) stations during and somewhat after the movie Code era were licensed by the FCC to 'serve the public good'; FCC had a few outright prohibitions, like George Carlin's "seven dirty words", but also accepted complaints from the public, and a station that offended many viewers or listeners risked being shut down at a periodic license renewal hearing. And the then-only-three _networks_ each had a '[broadcast] standards & practices' department responsible for ensuring transmitted programs were 'acceptable'.